# Download location of WPF application

Tags: wpf

Can someone please tell me at which location files are downloaded on the local machine when a WPF application is downloaded?

Comment: Are you talking about a ClickOnce deployment?

Comment: Read about Isolated Storage, possibly, it is an answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx

Comment: Yes, Clickonce. I don't see the downloaded files in the location specified as the isolated storage in the above link. I am running Win Server 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XP it is C:\Documents and Settings\${Username}\Local Settings\Apps\2.0... That directory is quite convoluted so enter at your own risk. :)